# Can 1801-1831 censuses in England be viewed online?

Tags: 19th-century, england, census-records

Can the 1801-1831 censuses in England be viewed online?

If so, where and how?

Answer (score 3):

A good number of them have survived and are available in document form at archives (as described at [Census schedules and listings, 1801-
1831: an introduction and guide](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/history/documents/research/RT2_Wall_2012.pdf).

However, they are not (as far as I know) online anywhere and are unlikely to be made available by the big genealogy data companies because of the mixed nature of the information collected and recocorded -- in some instances, only statistical data was recorded, but in others nominal data is included as well. If your place of interest recorded nominal data, they can be very useful but you will have to go to a local archive to consult them.

[1911census.org.uk](http://www.1911census.org.uk/1831.htm) gives useful information about what data was collected (this link leads to the 1831 information but they also cover 1801 - 1821.